# Issues with HQL when performing search using "Exists"

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, exists, mappingexception

I'm having trouble translating this sql:

```
select * from documentos d where 
         exists (select 1 from documento_timestamp dt 
                          where d.id_documento = dt.id_documento 
                          and dt.fecha between sysdate - 41 and sysdate -39 
                          and dt.estado = 'RC');
```

query into Hibernate using criteria.

Here's the Documento entity mapping:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "DOCUMENTOS")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_DOC_ELECTRONICOS", sequenceName = "SEQ_DOC_ELECTRONICOS", allocationSize = 1)
    public class Documento implements Serializable { // NOPMD by gpautasso on 17/09/13 11:01
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_DOC_ELECTRONICOS")
        @Column(name = "ID_DOCUMENTO")
        private long idDocumento;

        @Column(name = "COD_IDENTIFICATORIO")
        private String codigoIdentificatorio;

        @Column(name = "CUIT_CLIENTE")
        private Long cuitCliente;

        @Column(name = "RAZON_SOCIAL")
        private String razonSocial;

        @Column(name = "ORIGEN")
        private String origen;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "CODIGO_DOCUMENTO", referencedColumnName = "CODIGO_DOCUMENTO")
        private CodigoDocumentos codigoDocumento;

        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        @Column(name = "FECHA_ENVIO")
        private Calendar fechaEnvio;

        @Column(name = "EXTENSION")
        private String extension;

        @Column(name = "TAMANO")
        private String tamano;

        @Column(name = "BDOCUMENTO")
        private byte[] documentoBynary;

        @Lob
        @Column(name = "XML_DOCUMENTO")
        private String xmlDocumento;

        @Column(name = "ESTADO")
        private String estado;

        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        @Column(name = "FECHA_ESTADO")
        private Calendar fechaEstado;

        @Column(name = "CLAVE_VINCULACION")
        private String claveVinculacion;

        @Column(name = "NOMBRE_ARCHIVO")
        private String nombreArchivo;

        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        @Column(name = "TMSP_FECHA")
        private Calendar tmspFecha;

        @Column(name = "TMSP_ESTADO")
        private String tmspEstado;

        @Column(name = "COD_CLIENTE")
        private Long codCliente;

        @Column(name = "INFORMAR_TIB")
        private String informarTIB;

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
        @JoinColumn(name = "ID_DOCUMENTO")
        private List<DocumentoDestinatarios> documentoDestinatariosList;

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
        @JoinColumn(name = "ID_DOCUMENTO")
        private List<DocumentoDestinatariosMail> documentoDestinatariosMailList;

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
        @JoinColumn(name = "ID_DOCUMENTO")
        private List<DocumentoInformacion> documentoInformacionList;

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
        @JoinColumn(name = "ID_DOCUMENTO")
        private List<DocumentoReferencias> documentoReferenciasList;

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
        @JoinColumn(name = "ID_DOCUMENTO")
        private List<DocumentoTimestamp> documentoTimestampList;

        @Column(name = "FECHA_LIMITE_VISUALIZACION")
        private Calendar fechaLimiteVisualizacion;
```

Documento_timestamp entity mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DOCUMENTO_TIMESTAMP")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_DOC_TIMESTAMP", sequenceName = "SEQ_DOC_TIMESTAMP", allocationSize = 1)
public class DocumentoTimestamp implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_DOC_TIMESTAMP")
    @Column(name = "ID_TIMESTAMP")
    private long idDocumentoTimestamp;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST })
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_DOCUMENTO")
    private Documento documento;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "FECHA")
    private Date fecha;

    @Column(name = "ESTADO")
    private String estado;

    @Column(name = "OBSERVACION")
    private String observacion;

    @Column(name = "ORIGEN")
    private String origen;

    @Column(name = "TIPO_DOC")
    private String tipoDocumentoConsulta;

    @Column(name = "NRO_DOC")
    private Long numeroDocumentoConsulta;

    @Column(name = "CUIT")
    private Long cuit;

    @Column(name = "RAZON_SOCIAL")
    private String razonSocial;

    @Column(name = "DESC_UNIFICADA")
    private String descUnificada;
```

Finally here's what I came up with so far:

```
Session session = (Session) this.getSession();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Documento.class, "doc").setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

        DetachedCriteria timestampCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(DocumentoTimestamp.class, "documento_timestamp");
        if (!StringUtils.esVacioONull(request.getFechaRecepcionDesde())) {
            Calendar fechaDesde = DateUtils.transform2Calendar((request.getFechaRecepcionDesde()) + "000000", DateUtils.YYYYMMDDHHMMSS);
            timestampCriteria.add(Restrictions.ge("FECHA", fechaDesde));                
        }           
        if (!StringUtils.esVacioONull(request.getFechaRecepcionHasta())) {
            Calendar fechaHasta = DateUtils.transform2Calendar((request.getFechaRecepcionHasta()) + "235959", DateUtils.YYYYMMDDHHMMSS);
            timestampCriteria.add(Restrictions.le("FECHA", fechaHasta));                
        }   
        timestampCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("ESTADO", "RC"));
        timestampCriteria.add(Property.forName("documento_timestamp.documento").eqProperty("doc.idDocumento"));
        criteria.add(Subqueries.exists(timestampCriteria.setProjection(Projections.property("documento_timestamp.documento"))));
```

Here's the stack trace

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: null
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:693)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getPropertyMapping(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:596)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getType(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:547)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getTypeUsingProjection(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:529)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getTypedValue(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:587)
at org.hibernate.criterion.SimpleExpression.getTypedValues(SimpleExpression.java:94)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getQueryParameters(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:315)
at org.hibernate.criterion.SubqueryExpression.createAndSetInnerQuery(SubqueryExpression.java:152)
at org.hibernate.criterion.SubqueryExpression.toSqlString(SubqueryExpression.java:69)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getWhereCondition(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:380)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.<init>(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:113)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.<init>(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:82)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.<init>(CriteriaLoader.java:92)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1697)
at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:347)
at ar.com.ib.gde.domain.dao.DocumentoDaoImpl.consultaListadoDocumentosTimestamp(DocumentoDaoImpl.java:218)
at ar.com.ib.gde.domain.dao.DocumentoDaoImpl_vv3zuk_DocumentoDaoImpl.__WL_invoke(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionLocalMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionLocalMethodInvoker.java:31)
at ar.com.ib.gde.domain.dao.DocumentoDaoImpl_vv3zuk_DocumentoDaoImpl.consultaListadoDocumentosTimestamp(Unknown Source)
at ar.com.ib.gde.ejb.factory.DocumentosFactory.consultaListadoDocumentosTimestamp(DocumentosFactory.java:135)
at ar.com.ib.gde.business.ConsultaDocumento.consultaListadoDocumentosTimestamp(ConsultaDocumento.java:522)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.MethodInvocationInvocationContext.proceed(MethodInvocationInvocationContext.java:103)
at ar.com.ib.gde.interceptors.RuleInterceptor.executeBusiness(RuleInterceptor.java:62)
at ar.com.ib.gde.interceptors.RuleInterceptor.execute(RuleInterceptor.java:29)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.JeeInterceptorInterceptor.invoke(JeeInterceptorInterceptor.java:108)
at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.MethodInvocationInvocationContext.proceed(MethodInvocationInvocationContext.java:103)
at ar.com.ib.gde.interceptors.ErrorRuleInterceptor.execute(ErrorRuleInterceptor.java:25)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you print the stack trace?

Comment: It seems that your configuration xml file is missing your entity and transactional relationship. Check if you have everything done properly.